# Работа с API православный календарь azbuka.ru

Tags: javascript, get, calendar

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как отправить GET запрос на api с токеном на javascript https://azbyka.ru/days/api/ по эндпоинту texts/{id} с заданным типом type от 1 до 12 с вот таким json { "id":   integer, "type":    integer, "text": "string", "title": "string", "url": "string" }

У меня получается получить текст с этого API и токен, но **не получается выдать id с type которым я хочу.** И у меня не получается влиять на этот API в строке, например "https://azbyka.ru/days/api/texts/5?type=5" вот так не получается =(. Код ниже.

```
const requestURL = 'https://azbyka.ru/days/api/texts/5';


function sendRequest(method, url, body = null) {
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${api_token}`,
  }
  
  return fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    headers: headers
  }).then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json()
    }

    return response.json().then(error => {
      const e = new Error('Что-то пошло не так')
      e.data = error
      throw e
    })
  })
}

sendRequest('GET', requestURL)
  .then(data => console.log(data.text))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```